# multiple sed command in one .rc file, break if one not found

Tags: sed

I put multiple sed command in one .rc file so I can finish the replacing work by source xxx.rc

the .rc looks like:

```
sed -i "pattern\[0\]/sub\[0\]/g" my_file
sed -i "pattern\[1\]/sub\[1\]/g" my_file
sed -i "pattern\[2\]/sub\[2\]/g" my_file`
...
sed -i "pattern\[n\]/sub\[n\]/g" my_file
```

but if pattern[1] not exits in my_file, the rest of the sed command would not be executed so my file just stop in the half way.

I want to ask if there is some method to move forward next sed command no matter what last one return, or a method I can do like if (pattern[0] exist) { sed 0} ... therefore make the sed serial not break ?`

Comment: `but if pattern[1] not exits in my_file, the rest of the sed command would not be executed so my file just stop in the half way.` why? `to move forward next sed command no matter` Is there a method to "not move"? What is executing that `rc` file? `pattern\[0\]/sub\[0\]/g` is an invalid sed script.

Comment: Try to add `|| true` at the end of each line

Comment: put them all in 1 sed script, i.e. `sed 's/1/X/g;s/2/Y/g;s/3/Z/g' file` ? Good luck.

Comment: If the substitution is proper sed syntax, sed will return zero whether it matches or not.  So the script should continue.  Chances are there is malformed sed in one invocation, in which case sed will throw an error.  Note that *none* of the sed commands in the OP will work.  They will all say "extra characters after command" because they all start with 'p' which is a sed command that takes no additional input.  They might only be missing `s/` to begin a substitution, however it's indicative of sed behavior that will throw an error.

Comment: Assuming that `sed -i "pattern\[0\]/sub\[0\]/g" my_file` is supposed to be `sed -i "s/pattern\[0\]/sub\[0\]/g" my_file` - have you considered just doing one `sed -Ei 's/pattern(\[[0-9]+]])/sub\1/g'` instead of all those different sed commands?